# Hidden TextInput in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am working on a project wherein I am connected to a Scanner. Scanner, when scanned, will send the text. Right now I am having a Text Input (hidden) field to get the details from the Scanner but the issue I am facing is Keyboard is getting displayed when the Text Input got focus. I have tried to use Keyboard.dismiss() but  this is removing the focus also from TextInput (and now the text returned from Scanner is no longer listened by the TextInput). How can I approach this problem?

Following is the code

```
 <TextInput
            style={Style.hiddenInput}
            autoFocus={true}
            multiline
            onFocus={Keyboard.dismiss}
            onChangeText={this._onHiddenTextChangeText}
            value={this.state.hiddenInput}
          />
```

Styles

```
 hiddenInput: {
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
  },
```

Comment: What do you mean with "hidden" textInput? It doesn't actually show? it's disabled? Why do you need to focus it?

Comment: when your scanner return, you can use setState update the text

Comment: Do you mean you want to copy the text in TextInput?

Comment: Consider Scanner is an Input Device (Like Keyboard). Whatever you enter on the keyboard will be written only if it is a TextInput (or any control that can understand input). That is why I wanted to set the Focus. Why I want it to be a hidden field because I don't want the TextInput (texts from Scanner) to be displayed to the users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding the Native Package. I have added the example in the following github link

https://github.com/mohanprasathsj/reactnative-hidekeyboardonfocusexample

Comment: What about iOS?

Answer (score 2):

```html
<View style={{width:0,height:0}}>
<TextInput
            style={Style.hiddenInput}
            autoFocus={true}
            multiline
            onFocus={Keyboard.dismiss}
            onChangeText={this._onHiddenTextChangeText}
            value={this.state.hiddenInput}
          />
</View>
```

Comment: Add some more detail to your answer as only code will not help OP or other users who seek help in this topic.

Comment: onFocus={Keyboard.dismiss} works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best approach I can think of is to copy the scanned value to `Clipboard` (Possibly using the Scanner Settings) and check the data from `Clipboard` continuously.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getReadyToScan();
}

getReadyToScan() {
  try {
    let content = await Clipboard.getString();

    // Do whatever you want

    Clipboard.setString('');
  } catch (e) {
    Clipboard.setString('');
  } finally {
    // Adding a little bit of sleep
    setTimeout(() => this.getReadyToScan(), 200);
  }
}
```

There is request to add `keyboard='none'` to React-Native's TextInput but they have not gone around it yet.